# Concurrent job execution is not working in spring batch

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-batch

I want to execute the same job at the same time with different parameters.

Performed through JobLauncher.run(), a dummy job parameter was added to create a new Job Instance.

```
jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters)
```

The execution of the above code is done through http requests.

Simultaneous http requests are being made for testing.
If I look at the log, I can see that Step executions occur in parallel

```
2021-04-29 02:17:22.461  INFO 36040 --- [nio-8091-exec-4] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [RankingAggregationStep]

2021-04-29 02:17:23.065  INFO 36040 --- [nio-8091-exec-5] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [RankingAggregationStep]
```

However, the problem is that the Reader of the second request does not run immediately.

It is not until all steps in the first job instance have been completed that the Reader for the second reader instance(bean) is being created and performed.

As a result, Job is not running parallel.

```
@Configuration
class RankingAggregationJobConfig(
        private val jobBuilderFactory: JobBuilderFactory,
        private val stepBuilderFactory: StepBuilderFactory,
        private val aggregationService: AggregationService
) {

    companion object {
        const val DATA_SYNC_CHUNK = 100
    }

    @Bean
    fun rankingAggregationJob(): Job {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("rankingAggregationJob")
                .incrementer(RunIdIncrementer())
                .preventRestart()
                .start(rankingAggregationStep())
                .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun rankingAggregationStep(): Step {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("rankingAggregationStep")
                .chunk<RankingData, RankingData>(DATA_SYNC_CHUNK)
                .reader(rankingDataReader(null))
                .writer(rankingDataWriter())
                .build()
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    fun rankingDataReader(
            @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['total']}") total: RankingTotal?
    ): ListItemReader<RankingData> {

        val result = aggregationService.aggregate()

        return ListItemReader(result)
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    fun rankingDataWriter(): ItemWriter<RankingData> {
        return RankingDataWriter(aggregationService)
    }
}
```

How can I perform the Job in parallel? Please reply. Thank you

Comment: That should not be the case since you made your item reader step-scoped. I'm not able to reproduce the issue, see [this repo](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/main/issues/so67305163) where I start two job instances concurrently and both readers start at the same time. Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.